# ElasticSearch Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am new to ElasticSearch. I want to convert below query:

```
GET /snomed_v1/_analyze?analyzer=english
{ 12 O'clock, superior margin }
```

to the Java api query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect to your ES cluster as per the basics here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html

Your query will ask the admin interface for an AnalyzeRequest(index, query) with the english analyzer:

```
ESClient.admin().indices().analyze(new AnalyzeRequest("snomed_v1", "12 O'clock, superior margin").analyzer("english"));
```